# how to handle dynamic captcha values addition and enter in another checkbox using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Using the cypress Automation testing
I need to enter the captcha value shown in one checkbox and its have to type in another checkbox.
but the captcha values are dynamically changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FC9s.png)

Comment: The point of captchas is that the answers are entered by a human. This is to prevent bots from abusing a website. Automated tests are also a form of a bot and are therefore not possible. When testing, you could think about always generating the same captcha and enter the answer as you normally would using cypress.

Comment: ^ agreed. If this is an application you have control over and testing, then you should work with dev team to bypass or turn off captcha for testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, there is no way you can automate a captcha using an automated tool. In fact, the main purpose of using a captcha is to avoid bots/automated software accessing your websites. That being said, there could be some workarounds to get past this in lower environments like staging. Some of them could be as below.

1. Disable it in Non-production environments
2. Make it to use consistent images in lower environments so that you can hardcode the text in your automation scripts
3. See if there is a way to access the text through an API and then use it in your automated script

Comment: It's not very useful without some concrete examples. What is a "Lower environment"?

Comment: @TesterDick Thank you for pointing out the "lower environments". I have changed it.